# Как запустить app на localhost с загрузкой js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Запускаю проект командой node app.js , переходу на localhost и вижу следующее:

```
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8000/jquery.js» не удалась. localhost:8000:57:1
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8000/sheetrock.js» не удалась. localhost:8000:58:1
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8000/handlebars.js» не удалась. localhost:8000:59:1
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8000/js.js» не удалась.
```

второй вопрос, как разместить свой app на сервере? есть сервер, как сделать на него правильный deploy приложения? В проекте нет как такого файла index.html, всё должно собираться на лету. как сделать адресацию скриптов абсолютной (не добавлять вовнутрь localhost)

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть содержание файла app.js, чтобы помочь вам